# How autostart python script in RaspBerry Pi 3 (Raspbian (Debian))?

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, autostart

The problem is that I can not find the way for a Application.py file to auto-execute when the system starts. I have tried several ways; crontab, init.d, rc.local. And the sh script is executed, the problem is that the line where it is: `sudo /usr/lib/python3 /home/pi/file.py`, nothing happens. I know that the sh is executed, because I create a test1.log file and it is always created when starting.

On the other hand, if I manually execute `sudo /etc/init.d/startApp start`, everything runs normally and when you put `sudo /etc/init.d/inicioApp stop` the process stops. Next I leave the file `/etc/init.d/startApp`, to see if someone can help me, remember that Raspbian is running on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2.

The `/etc/init.d/startApp` file:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/startApp

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: startApp
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Application
# Description: Start Application.py automatically.
### END INIT INFO


case "$1" in
 start)
  echo "Start Application.py"
  echo "startApp is running" >> /home/pi/test1.log
  sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Application.py
  ;;

 stop)
  echo "Stop Application.py"
  /usr/bin/python3 -kill :1
  ;;

 *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/startApp {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The `/home/pi/Application.py` file:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys

try:
    import tkinter as tk  # Python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk  # Python 2

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO_present = True
GPIO_PULSE = 4
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_PULSE, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)


class Application(tk.Frame):
    DELAY = 100  # ms
    IMG_DELAY = 200
    POST_DELAY = 2000

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        print("executed")
        self.pack()
        self.w, self.h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.img_name = "/home/pi/pattern.png"
        self.control = 0
        self.create_widgets()
        self.flag = False
        self.after(self.DELAY, self.check_signal)
        root.bind('<Escape>', self.quitApp)

    def load_image(self, filename):

        try:
            pil_img = Image.open(filename)
            img_width, img_height = pil_img.size

            if img_width > self.w or img_height > self.h:  # Too big?
                size = (int(self.w), int(self.h))
                pil_img = pil_img.resize(size)
                ratio = min(self.w / img_width, self.h / img_height)
                img_width, img_height = int(img_width * ratio), int(img_height * ratio)
                pil_img = pil_img.resize((img_width, img_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Resize.
            self.control = 0
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)  # Convert to tkinter PhotoImage.
            return img

        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.control = 1

    def quitApp(self, a):
        root.destroy()

    def create_widgets(self):
        file = open("testfile.txt", "w")

        file.write("Se ejecuto.py")

        file.close()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=self.w, height=self.h, background='black')
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.pattern_img = self.load_image(self.img_name)
        if self.control == 1:
            sys.exit()
            root.destroy()

        self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(self.w / 2, self.h / 2, image=None)

    def show_image(self):
        self.cur_img = self.pattern_img
        self.after(self.IMG_DELAY)
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.image_id, image=self.cur_img)
        self.update()
        self.after(self.POST_DELAY)
        self.canvas.delete(self.image_id)
        self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(self.w / 2, self.h / 2, image=None)

    def check_signal(self):

        if GPIO_present:
            self.flag = not GPIO.input(GPIO_PULSE)

        if self.flag:
            self.show_image()
            self.flag = False  # Reset

        root.after(self.DELAY, self.check_signal)  # Check again after delay.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 'true')
    root.focus_set()

app = Application(root)

app.mainloop()
```

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: That the Application.py file indicated on the line that says `sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Application.py` does not start, which does happen when I manually launch the command `sudo /etc/init.d/startApp start`. I explain myself well? Thank you

Comment: The test.txt is created by `Application.py`? If so that means your application is running... have you tried a simpler python script like `print("It works!")`?

Comment: Have you tried [any of these methods](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/)?

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the name of the file, since I modified it, it was not test.txt, the file I speak of is test1.log. Sorry again!

Comment: All no, I go to it and comment if anyone works, thank you!

Comment: If the script is for sure executed because of the log, it means something went wrong with executing the `Application.py`.  Either a permission problem, `python3` not starting, or the `.py` itself is the issue.  I'd suggest try some really simple script to see if `sudo /usr/bin/python3` runs first, like a simple `with open('testfile.txt', 'w') as file: file.write("hey")` and look for `testfile.txt`.

Comment: No, I have already been able to test those 5 methods and none run the Application.py script, the methods work, but at the moment the flame is made `sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Application.py`, none comes to execute. Yes, if the execution is forced once the system is started, if it works in cases that are possible, that's why the only thing that occurs to me is that Python is not loaded, but the others also work in Raspbian and Raspberry, I do not know what it could be :/

Comment: @Idlehands
I have tried what you say and python3 works perfectly and create the text file with what I write, and the Application.py file runs normally if I do it manually with python3, I do not understand it, I give the permissions as indicated in the tutorials / guides but it does not work for me.

Comment: Then perhaps it's more helpful to show the content of what your `Application.py`.  It could be faililng due to reliance on relative path instead of absolute path or other factors.  Your `cwd` when you run it manually vs autostart might be different.

Comment: @Idlehands
Look at the post, I have updated it and now you have the content of the Application.py file, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running raspbian isn't it?

Since Debian 7 (raspbian is based on Debian) the default init system is **systemd**, nonetheless there is compatibility with the old known **systemv**, so you can still use the /etc/init.d/youscript approach but please make sure to:

- Grant execution permissions for your init.d script startApp
- Choose which runlevels do you want the startApp to be executed, i.e 5,3, etc you can find your default runlevel with:

```
sudo runlevel
```

- Use update-rc.d to put your script in the boot startup for the default runlevel (that way you don't have to worry about if the default is the /etc/rc5.d or /etc/rc2.d it does it for you )

```
update-rc.d script-name default
```

- (**Optional if not using update-rc.d**) Create a soft link and point it to the right runlevel directory /etc/rcX.d but mind the name!, is important that will have an 'S' for start and a number like '99' as you want it to be executed at the very end of the runlevel start sequence, i.e:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/startApp /etc/rc5.d/S99startApp
```